# How to access function inside map?

Tags: javascript, map-function

Yes, I know, there's a lot of info about this, but i can't make it work.
I'm trying to access the function `checkType` inside the map in `update` function, but I get the well known `TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkType' of undefined`

Show you some code:

```
function builder() {
return {
    update(data){
        let keys = someFunctionGettinTheKeys();
        let query = keys.map((key) => key + ' = ' . **this.checkType(data[key])**);
        return query;
    },
    checkType(data){
        /*...some code...*/
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried:

- Binding 'this'
- Old fashioned map
- Passing 'this' as parameter to map

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing it right. What's wrong is how you call `update`, not as a method on the builder instance. Please post that code as well.

Comment: Is that point after `' = '` supposed to be a plus?

Comment: Um, what is `.` doing? Is someone mixing up php with javascript syntax.

Comment: Omg...O M G...that was it. Never saw that dot. I replaced it with a + and now it works.

Man...can't believe I missed that damn dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that dot right before the function call. I replaced that dot with a '+' and now it works.
That was all. Embarrasing, but true.

Answer (score 0):

**Array.prototype.map()** takes a second argument to set what this refers to in the mapping function, so pass this as the second argument to preserve the current context:

```
arr.map(function(el) {
...
}, this);
```

Your code changes =>

```js
function builder() {
    return {
    update: function() {
      let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
      let newArr = arr.map((element) => {
        return this.check(element)
      }, this);
      console.log(newArr)
    },
    check: function(num) {
            return num * 2;
    }
  }
}

builder().update();
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you not just do the following?

```js
function bulider(){
  const checkType = (data) => {
    /* do type check */
    return 'text'
  }
  return {
    update(data) {
      let keys = someFunctionGettinTheKeys()
      let query = keys.map((key) => key + ' = ' + checkType(data[key]))
      return query
    },
    checkType: checkType
  }
}
```

usage:

```js
const { update } = builder()
const transformedData = update(data)
```